# I'm using Xamarin Form 5.0 Clearing Cookies on both platform code not working

Tags: xamarin

this code is deprecated in Xamarin

Android

```
        var cookieManager = CookieManager.Instance;
        cookieManager.RemoveAllCookie();
```

iOS

```
        NSHttpCookieStorage CookieStorage = NSHttpCookieStorage.SharedStorage;
        foreach (var cookie in CookieStorage.Cookies)
            CookieStorage.DeleteCookie(cookie);
```

Please help im doing sign out page.

Comment: I'm using Web Authenticator

Answer (score 0):

In ios, you can try the following code:

```
public void Clear()
{
  NSHttpCookieStorage.SharedStorage.RemoveCookiesSinceDate(NSDate.DistantPast);
  WKWebsiteDataStore.DefaultDataStore.FetchDataRecordsOfTypes(WKWebsiteDataStore.AllWebsiteDataTypes, (NSArray records) => {

        for (System.nuint i = 0; i < records.Count; i++)
        {
            var record = records.GetItem<WKWebsiteDataRecord>(i);
            WKWebsiteDataRecord[] recordArray = new WKWebsiteDataRecord[record.DataTypes.Count];
            WKWebsiteDataStore.DefaultDataStore.RemoveDataOfTypes(record.DataTypes, NSDate.DistantPast, () => { });
        }

    });
}
```

Here is the android solution:

```
 public async Task Clear() {
    var cookieManager = CookieManager.Instance; 
    cookieManager.RemoveAllCookie(); 
  }
```

Refer: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/12999#issuecomment-817791640

Comment: hello, i'm using web authenticator still not working man :(